# Flask: How to pass url as an input?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, flask, flask-restful, url-parsing

The requirement is to pass an url as an input to the endpoint.

The url may look like this:

```
"google.com:443/something/something.html?q=go+lang"
```

How can I pass it to my api get method as `localhost:5001/api/google.com:443/something/something.html?q=go+lang`

Currently, I am using Flask and Flask-restful
even if I encoded the url to

```
google.com%3A443%2Fsomething%2Fsomething.html%3Fq%3Dgo%2Blang
```

and pass it to my api

```
api.add_resource(UrlInfo, '/api/<encoded_url>')
```

The system won't take it as a whole. It will decoded it and return 404

I would like to ask if there's a proper way that I can pass the url as a whole?
the url may contains multiple level (slashes) in the path. How can I handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
api.add_resource(UrlInfo, '/api/<path:encoded_url>')
```

Reference: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

---

Here's what I tried, definitely works:

```
route('/testurl/<path:input_url>')
def testurl(input_url):
    return input_url
```

URL called: http://127.0.0.1:5000/codesubmission/testurl/http://www.google.com/testthisout/

Output on page: http://www.google.com/testthisout/

Answer (score 0):

So, you just want to loop through a list of URLs?  Is that all?  The the sample code below and feedback.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests  
import pandas as pd  

url_list = ['http://www.no1.com',
'http://www.no2.com',
'http://www.no3.com']
   for link in url_list:
```